# About azure devops personal access token authentication

Tags: api, rest, authentication, azure-devops

Is login authentication done each time I request each wiki page content of azure devops through Rest API?

Note: If authentication done each time then is there any alternative to authonticate because I have limited login attempts

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are using the Azure DevOps PAT to call the REST API [`Wikis - Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/Wikis/Get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). If so, it does the authentication each time when you request the API.

> If authentication done each time then is there any alternative to authenticate because I have limited login attempts

The PAT(personal access token) does not have an authentication times limitation, it just has an expired time, you can use it to do the authentication for any time before the expired time.

If you still want to authenticate to Azure DevOps REST API with other ways, you have two other options.

1.Use OAuth 2.0, see [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops).

2.Use Azure AD token, see [Authenticate with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#authenticate-with-azure-active-directory-azure-ad-tokens).